Batch jobs in microservice with Apache spark as a solution
We are considering the implementation of a microservice architecture for multiple business domains, like Customer, Product, Payment, and Collections. Each of these domains contains 20-40 sets of database tables where the respective data is stored.
The proposed microservices would be responsible for extracting and updating data within their respective domains. There are multiple batch jobs, would consume data from these various business domains as per their data processing needs. For instance, the Payment Process would consume data from both the Payment and Customer domains, and perform operations such as insert, update, and delete on the payment domain-related tables. It might also update data on the customer side.
As we move from Customer towards Collections, the complexity of this processing increases. Each single batch job will read, insert, update, delete, and process millions of records.
We have several key questions to answer as we design this data architecture:
   How do we design this for processing batch programs that can read, process, and update data with complex computing?
   Should we divide the database into different domain-specific data or keep everything in one single database?
   Should the batch program consume data only via the respective microservice, or should it directly connect to the database and read/update the data?
We are considering Apache Spark as a potential solution for processing this massive amount of data. But there are few challenges:
   What should be the programming language used for integrating Apache Spark (Java or Python)?
   What database could we consider for this massive volume and velocity of data storage and processing?
Your insights and suggestions on these matters would be greatly appreciated.
We tried the option of apache spark but there is huge volume of data, need to check how can we hold respective data?
